# Sending e-mails out of the main PHP thread

Tags: php

In my wesbite, when a user submit a form, I need to update my DB and send several e-mails (to him, to admin, ...)

For now, I'm doing in inside the target page of the form.php (which in my case is also form.php). The problem is that sending e-mails takes a while. And from the user point of view, it just seems that the page takes a while to load.

Is there a way that the e-mails will be done on a separate "thread" so that I the user doesn't have to wait the emails to be sent?

Comment: Ideally you want a queue-worker system. Google for that, plenty out there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery ajax to this. 
Simply send the necessary information that needs to be stored to a backend php file and have the emailing code in that file. It will have the emails sent to you behind the curtain.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: backend.php,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Have your backend file do the needful saving and emailing. 
Also, you can use a queue worker system, but I don't how effective it would be to you.
Depends on the complexity and size of the app IMHO.